# Sorting Dictionary by Value and Printing Keys only

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, printing

Let's say that I have a dictionary as follow:

```
dictionary = {"A": "9",  "B": "8",  "C": 10}
```

I want to print the keys only for the dictionary but sorted according to the value of the key. For example, I want it to be sorted according to the biggest value to the smallest value (on the same line).

So the output of this should be

```
C A B
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can sort a dict, to sort it you need to make list of tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
print(' '.join(sorted(dictionary.keys(),key=lambda x: -dictionary[x])))
```

Output:

```
C A B
```